# Can I use a 220V rated LED lamp on a 110V line?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I am presuming the answer of this is no. (I haven't tried to use a 220V bulb from the supplier before but their supply of 110V or Wide Voltage bulbs is limited.)

[E27 6W LED Maïs Lamp Koud Wit 750lm 6500K 69-SMD (AC 220V ~ 240V)](https://www.dx.com/p/e27-6w-led-corn-lamp-cool-white-light-750lm-6500k-69-smd-5730-ac-220v-240v-2056614.html)

Is it safe to use this on a 110V power line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably not, since it's an LED bulb; and while there seem to be very few details on the website, the link calls it out as 220-240V. Some "wide range" LED supplies work from 85V to 277V but this is almost certainly not one of those.

An old-fashioned incandescent 240V bulb will work fine on 120V, at roughly 1/4 power, and thus it will be dim and yellow (but it will also last a very long time.) But that is not what you linked.

Answer (score 4):

### NEC prohibits use of that junk

DealExtreme is all dangerous trash; it's the exact same cheap Cheese junkstream as AliExpress, BangGood, eBay and Amazon Marketplace.  *Buying anything from them that touches mains power is simply out of the question*.  NEC 110.2.

### NEC also prohibits misapplication

Further, NEC 110.3(B) applies, which requires you to obey labeling and instructions. **The labeling plainly says 220-240V.  So no**.

Answer (score -1):

It will work.  Im using IKEA branded Australian 240v LEDs bulbs on 110v. And no discernable difference in lumens.

Comment: Yes, but you can't give a guarantee unless you had tried the same exact bulb.